# Meet vs Meet with

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

I learned that 'meet' meant encountering a person for the first time and 'meet with' meant spending time with someone for discussion (business, politics, etc.)

Recently I came across [this](https://www.myhappyenglish.com/free-english-lesson/2012/05/02/english-lesson-meet-vs-see/) post where it says that 'meet' is also used when you make an appointment, plans, or have a schedule. In this case meet means “we have an appointment or a meeting scheduled.”

Here are two sentences:

- I met with/**met** Cathy to plan the office Christmas party.
- The president is going to meet with/**meet** the prime minister on Friday.

Can 'meet' be used instead of 'meet with' in these sentences even if the people aren't meeting for the first time?

Comment: For these, 'meet' is mainly British, and 'meet with' mainly American.

Comment: So in AmE we can use 'meet' both for meeting someone for the first time and meeting for appointment/business even if it's not the first time? I wonder if it's possible to say "I'm meeting Cathy at the coffee shop" even if Cathy is your friend and you meet her often?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.